In a completely regular space with two disjoint closed subsets, one compact, both closed, can be separated by a continuous function?
I just want to verify my proof is correct and ask questions?
The problem is: let $X$ be completely regular. Let $A, B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X.$ Show that if $A$ is compact, there is a continuous function $f: X \longrightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $f(A) = \{0\}, f(B) = \{1\}.$
Recall Uryshon's Lemma says that if $X$ is completely regular and $A, B \subset X$ are closed then there exists a continuous function $f: X \to [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in B.$
We can apply Uryshon's Lemma to the statement so there exists a continuous $\pi: X \to [0, 1]$ such that $\pi(x) = 1$ for all $x \in B$ and $\pi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$.
\begin{equation}
 \pi(x) = \begin{cases} 
        1, & \text{if } x \in B\\
        0, & \text{if } x \in A\\
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Define another function $\phi: X \to [0, 1]$ as follows: $\phi(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\pi(x) + 1}.$ Now, $\phi$ is continuous since it is the composition of continuous functions. Note that:
\begin{equation}
 \phi(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } x \in B\\
        0, & \text{if } x \in A\\
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Define $U = \{x \in X: \phi(x) = 0\}$. $U$ forms an open cover of $A$. Since $A$ is compact, $U$ has a finite subcover that covers $A.$ Also, The complement of $U, U^c,$ must form an open cover for $B.$ However, we can't say if $U^c$ has a finite subcover since it wasn't given that $B$ is compact.
Finally, define $f: X \to [0, 1]$ as a piecewise function:
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \begin{cases} 
        0, & \text{if } x < \frac{1}{2}\\
        1, & \text{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1\\
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
To show $f$ is continuous we only need to check continuity at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. The limit from both sides exists (trivial to show) to it is continuous. I'm not sure if a $\delta -
\epsilon$ proof is required here or what I wrote suffices.
\begin{equation}
 (f \circ \phi)(x) = \begin{cases} 
        0, & \text{if } x \in A\\
        1, & \text{if } x \in B\\
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Since $f \circ \phi$ is the the composition of continuous functions it is continuous. So, the function $f \circ \phi$ satisfies the statement.
Is this ok? Why is $A$ being compact important? I didn't use it in my proof that $A$ being compact means its cover $U$ has a finite subcover.

I don't see what is the difference between the stated problem and Urysohn's lemma. Why can't you just take $\pi$ itself?

$A$ doesn't even need to be compact.

@K.Jiang it does need to be compact

@Mark This problem is slightly different from Urysohn's lemma. Its more related to that in a Hausdorff space disjoint closed sets, one of them compact, can be separated. Here its the same argument

@Jakobian Can you explain why $A$ needs to be compact? I don't see it.

@KevinDeCara Urysohn's lemma holds for normal space $X$, not completely regular. For a completely regular space $X$, you are only guaranteed that if $A$ is closed and $x\notin A$ then there exists a continuous function $f:X\to [0, 1]$ with $f(A)\subseteq {0}$ and $f(x) = 1$

That is, the "Urysohn's lemma" holds for disjoint $A$ a closed set and $B = {x}$ a singleton. Not for arbitrary closed sets $A, B$. Also a minor point is that $B$ doesn't have to be closed, but its less important.

@Jakobian But then I believe OP should not be allowed to use Urysohn's lemma, right?

@Mark OP definitely can't use Urysohn's lemma in this problem. Urysohn's lemma is equivalent to a space being normal, but there exist spaces which are completely regular but not normal.

Note that this is the same problem as in the duplicate for compact $C$ and closed set $U^c$ disjoint from it.

I'd phrase it like this: Let $A$ be compact. We can find a zero set neighbourhood $Z_x$ of $x$ and $W_x$ of $B$ for every $x\in A$. By compactness there is finite amount $x_1, ..., x_n\in A$ with $\text{int}(Z_{x_i})$ covering $A$. Then $Z = \bigcup_i Z_{x_i}$ is a zero set neighbourhood of $A$ and $W = \bigcap_i W_{x_i}$ is a zero set neighbourhood of $B$, $Z\cap W = \emptyset$. Now there exists a function $f:X\to [0, 1]$ with $f(Z)\subseteq {0}$ and $f(W)\subseteq {1}$ (exercise). This is also the desired function.

A zero set is a set of the form $Z(g) = {x\in X : g(x) = 0}$ for some continuous function $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$. One can show they are closed under countable intersections and finite unions.

@Jakobian Thank you.
